# What are the typical scales of multivariate regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am about to receive a dataset for multivariate regression where we are trying to find $X\in\Re^{m\times n}$ such that it best fits the loss function $$\|AX-B\|_F^2$$ where $A\in \Re^{l\times m},B\in\Re^{l\times n}$.

For some other purposes, what I was wondering was, what are the typical proportions for $A,X,B$ in most datasets?

I am looking for ballpark estimates; I would assume $A$ is usually very tall but how many columns would it have? How many columns would $B$ have?

If there are any freely available datasets for me to play with, if you can, please give link. I was not able to find any purely numerical datasets on the UCI ML repository.